# PHP Simple HTML Dom: Prepend

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to get this code:

```
<div class="class1">Any Text<div>Or any other Content</div></div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="class1 another_class"><div class="extra"></div>Any Text<div>Or any other Content</div></div>
```

with the PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser

This is my first part:

```
foreach($html->find(".class1") as $element) {
    $element->class="class1 another_class";
}
```

But how can I add the "extra"-div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

($e->innertext)Read or write the inner HTML text of element.
may be this gonna work.. :)

```
foreach($html->find("div.class1") as $element) {
    $element->innertext = '<div class="extra"></div>' . $element->innertext;
    $element->class = "class1 another_class";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is this;

```
$ret = $html->find('div.foo');
//OR
$ret = $html->find('div[class=foo]');
```

source: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm
How to find HTML elements? section, tab Advanced

Comment: I am not sure can ask at here, What is PHP Simple HTML Dom?, you got any good link for review it.

Comment: @CheongBC It's an html parser for php

Comment: As in the manual shown the syntax is correct: 
$ret = $html->find('.foo');